# Creating a Spider Chart where each arm on the web scales independently

Tags: python, powerbi, visualization, deneb

I need to build a KPI spider chart that compares the current period, the target value, and prior periods performance.  Below, I have a simple example of what I am trying to build, it is just Word Art/Images because I have not been able to build a similar visualization in Power BI. The issue that I am having, is that each of the visualizations I have tried, set scale for the entire visualizing, not by each element it contains.

I am comfortable exploring a Python solution but none of my searches have pointed me in the direction I need to go.

I have been shown examples of what my boss is looking for so I assume this is possible but none of my research or attempts have been successful, if anyone can point me towards a resource or example using either Python or Power BI, it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Deneb and the Vega template here to create a nice spider chart in PowerBI. It will be fully interactive too unlike a Python visual.

https://deneb-viz.github.io/

https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/radar-chart/
[image]

Each spoke of the web can have its own scale too.

Here is a faceted spider chart I created recently that exactly meets these requirements.

[image]

Full code can be found as a .pbix on my LinkedIn profile.

https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7032714645073219584/

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "Dataviz by Dav Bacci",
  "width": 1050,
  "background": "#343537",
  "height": 750,
  "padding": {
    "top": 80,
    "left": 40,
    "right": 85
  },
  "autosize": {
    "type": "none",
    "contains": "padding"
  },
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "radius",
      "update": "(width / 6)-92"
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {
          "key": "key-0",
          "value": 19,
          "category": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "key-1",
          "value": 22,
          "category": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "key-2",
          "value": 14,
          "category": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "key-3",
          "value": 38,
          "category": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "key-4",
          "value": 23,
          "category": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "key-5",
          "value": 5,
          "category": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "key-6",
          "value": 27,
          "category": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "key-0",
          "value": 13,
          "category": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "key-1",
          "value": 12,
          "category": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "key-2",
          "value": 42,
          "category": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "key-3",
          "value": 13,
          "category": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "key-4",
          "value": 6,
          "category": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "key-5",
          "value": 15,
          "category": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "key-6",
          "value": 8,
          "category": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "source",
      "values": [
        {
          "Name": "Easy Pancakes",
          "Link": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/easy-pancakes",
          "Type": "Sweet",
          "Prep Time (Mins)": 10,
          "Cooking Time (Mins)": 20,
          "Difficulty": "Easy",
          "kcal": 61,
          "fat (g)": 2,
          "saturates (g)": 1,
          "carbs (g)": 7,
          "sugars (g)": 1,
          "fibre (g)": 0,
          "protein (g)": 3,
          "salt (g)": 0.1
        },
        {
          "Name": "American Pancakes",
          "Link": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/american-pancakes",
          "Type": "Sweet",
          "Prep Time (Mins)": 25,
          "Cooking Time (Mins)": 30,
          "Difficulty": "Easy",
          "kcal": 356,
          "fat (g)": 13,
          "saturates (g)": 6,
          "carbs (g)": 46,
          "sugars (g)": 8,
          "fibre (g)": 2,
          "protein (g)": 13,
          "salt (g)": 1.25
        },
        {
          "Name": [
            "American Blueberry",
            "Pancakes"
          ],
          "Link": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/american-blueberry-pancakes",
          "Type": "Sweet",
          "Prep Time (Mins)": 15,
          "Cooking Time (Mins)": 20,
          "Difficulty": "Easy",
          "kcal": 108,
          "fat (g)": 0,
          "saturates (g)": 1,
          "carbs (g)": 18,
          "sugars (g)": 0,
          "fibre (g)": 1,
          "protein (g)": 4,
          "salt (g)": 0.41
        },
        {
          "Name": [
            "Chocolate Filled Pancakes",
            " with Caramelised Banana"
          ],
          "Link": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/chocolate-filled-pancakes-caramelised-banana",
          "Type": "Sweet",
          "Prep Time (Mins)": 25,
          "Cooking Time (Mins)": 30,
          "Difficulty": "More effort",
          "kcal": 797,
          "fat (g)": 37,
          "saturates (g)": 12,
          "carbs (g)": 94,
          "sugars (g)": 57,
          "fibre (g)": 6,
          "protein (g)": 18,
          "salt (g)": 14
        },
        {
          "Name": [
            "Fluffy American Pancakes",
            "with Cherry-Berry Syrup"
          ],
          "Link": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/best-ever-fluffy-american-pancakes-cherry-berry-syrup",
          "Type": "Sweet",
          "Prep Time (Mins)": 10,
          "Cooking Time (Mins)": 30,
          "Difficulty": "Easy",
          "kcal": 233,
          "fat (g)": 11.75,
          "saturates (g)": 6.25,
          "carbs (g)": 24,
          "sugars (g)": 7.25,
          "fibre (g)": 1.25,
          "protein (g)": 7,
          "salt (g)": 0.775
        },
        {
          "Name": "Scotch Pancakes",
          "Link": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/scotch-pancakes",
          "Type": "Sweet",
          "Prep Time (Mins)": 10,
          "Cooking Time (Mins)": 15,
          "Difficulty": "Easy",
          "kcal": 121,
          "fat (g)": 3,
          "saturates (g)": 1,
          "carbs (g)": 19,
          "sugars (g)": 3,
          "fibre (g)": 1,
          "protein (g)": 4,
          "salt (g)": 0.5
        },
        {
          "Name": "Fluffy Japanese Pancakes",
          "Link": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/fluffy-japanese-pancakes",
          "Type": "Sweet",
          "Prep Time (Mins)": 10,
          "Cooking Time (Mins)": 90,
          "Difficulty": "Easy",
          "kcal": 174,
          "fat (g)": 4,
          "saturates (g)": 1,
          "carbs (g)": 27,
          "sugars (g)": 8,
          "fibre (g)": 1,
          "protein (g)": 6,
          "salt (g)": 0.4
        },
        {
          "Name": "Easy Banana Pancakes",
          "Link": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/easy-banana-pancakes",
          "Type": "Sweet",
          "Prep Time (Mins)": 5,
          "Cooking Time (Mins)": 10,
          "Difficulty": "Easy",
          "kcal": 161.3333333,
          "fat (g)": 2.333333333,
          "saturates (g)": 1,
          "carbs (g)": 87,
          "sugars (g)": 19,
          "fibre (g)": 5,
          "protein (g)": 15,
          "salt (g)": 1.21
        },
        {
          "Name": "Eggs Benedict Pancakes",
          "Link": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/eggs-benedict-pancakes",
          "Type": "Savoury",
          "Prep Time (Mins)": 10,
          "Cooking Time (Mins)": 20,
          "Difficulty": "Easy",
          "kcal": 605,
          "fat (g)": 36,
          "saturates (g)": 19,
          "carbs (g)": 46,
          "sugars (g)": 5,
          "fibre (g)": 2,
          "protein (g)": 23,
          "salt (g)": 2.14
        },
        {
          "Name": "Ham & Cheese Pancakes",
          "Link": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/smoked-ham-cheese-pancakes",
          "Type": "Savoury",
          "Prep Time (Mins)": 10,
          "Cooking Time (Mins)": 8,
          "Difficulty": "Easy",
          "kcal": 327,
          "fat (g)": 19,
          "saturates (g)": 10,
          "carbs (g)": 23,
          "sugars (g)": 2,
          "fibre (g)": 1,
          "protein (g)": 15,
          "salt (g)": 1.6
        },
        {
          "Name": "Crispy Duck Pancakes",
          "Link": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/crispy-duck-pancakes",
          "Type": "Savoury",
          "Prep Time (Mins)": 10,
          "Cooking Time (Mins)": 30,
          "Difficulty": "Easy",
          "kcal": 402,
          "fat (g)": 18,
          "saturates (g)": 5,
          "carbs (g)": 44,
          "sugars (g)": 19,
          "fibre (g)": 3,
          "protein (g)": 13,
          "salt (g)": 0.9
        }
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "joinaggregate",
          "fields": [
            "kcal",
            "fat (g)",
            "saturates (g)",
            "carbs (g)",
            "sugars (g)",
            "fibre (g)",
            "protein (g)",
            "salt (g)"
          ],
          "ops": [
            "max",
            "max",
            "max",
            "max",
            "max",
            "max",
            "max",
            "max"
          ],
          "as": [
            "max kcal",
            "max fat (g)",
            "max saturates (g)",
            "max carbs (g)",
            "max sugars (g)",
            "max fibre (g)",
            "max protein (g)",
            "max salt (g)"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "table3",
      "source": "source",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "window",
          "sort": {
            "field": "Name",
            "order": "ascending"
          },
          "ops": ["row_number"],
          "as": ["index"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "Time",
          "expr": "datum['Prep Time (Mins)']+datum['Cooking Time (Mins)']"
        },
        {
          "type": "joinaggregate",
          "fields": [
            "kcal",
            "fat (g)",
            "saturates (g)",
            "carbs (g)",
            "sugars (g)",
            "fibre (g)",
            "protein (g)",
            "salt (g)",
            "Time"
          ],
          "ops": [
            "mean",
            "mean",
            "mean",
            "mean",
            "mean",
            "mean",
            "mean",
            "mean",
            "mean"
          ],
          "as": [
            "m kcal",
            "m fat (g)",
            "m saturates (g)",
            "m carbs (g)",
            "m sugars (g)",
            "m fibre (g)",
            "m protein (g)",
            "m salt (g)",
            "m Time"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "fold",
          "fields": [
            "kcal",
            "fat (g)",
            "saturates (g)",
            "carbs (g)",
            "sugars (g)",
            "fibre (g)",
            "protein (g)",
            "salt (g)",
            "m kcal",
            "m fat (g)",
            "m saturates (g)",
            "m carbs (g)",
            "m sugars (g)",
            "m fibre (g)",
            "m protein (g)",
            "m salt (g)"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": [
            "Name",
            "Link",
            "Type",
            "Difficulty",
            "key",
            "value",
            "Time",
            "index",
            "m Time"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "value",
          "expr": "datum.key=='salt (g)'? round(datum.value *10)/10: round(datum.value )"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "category",
          "expr": "indexof(datum.key, 'm ')==-1?'data':'average'"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "key",
          "expr": "replace(datum.key, 'm ','')"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "table4",
      "source": "table3",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["key"]
        },
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "table3",
          "key": "key",
          "fields": ["key"],
          "as": ["value"],
          "values": ["value"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "index",
          "expr": "12"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "Name",
          "expr": "'Average'"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "category",
          "expr": "'data'"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "table5",
      "source": ["table3", "table4"]
    },
    {
      "name": "keys",
      "source": "table5",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["key"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "angular",
      "type": "point",
      "range": {"signal": "[-PI, PI]"},
      "padding": 0.5,
      "domain": {
        "data": "keys",
        "field": "key"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "kcal",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {
        "signal": "[0, radius]"
      },
      "zero": true,
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {
        "data": "source",
        "field": "kcal"
      },
      "domainMin": 0,
      "domainMax": {
        "signal": "data('source')[0]['max kcal']*1.3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "fat (g)",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {
        "signal": "[0, radius]"
      },
      "zero": true,
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {
        "data": "source",
        "field": "fat (g)"
      },
      "domainMin": 0,
      "domainMax": {
        "signal": "data('source')[0]['max fat (g)']*1.1"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "saturates (g)",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {
        "signal": "[0, radius]"
      },
      "zero": true,
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {
        "data": "source",
        "field": "saturates (g)"
      },
      "domainMin": 0,
      "domainMax": {
        "signal": "data('source')[0]['max saturates (g)']*1.2"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "carbs (g)",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {
        "signal": "[0, radius]"
      },
      "zero": true,
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {
        "data": "source",
        "field": "carbs (g)"
      },
      "domainMin": 0,
      "domainMax": {
        "signal": "data('source')[0]['max carbs (g)']*1.2"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "sugars (g)",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {
        "signal": "[0, radius]"
      },
      "zero": true,
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {
        "data": "source",
        "field": "sugars (g)"
      },
      "domainMin": 0,
      "domainMax": {
        "signal": "data('source')[0]['max sugars (g)']*1.2"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "fibre (g)",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {
        "signal": "[0, radius]"
      },
      "zero": true,
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {
        "data": "source",
        "field": "fibre (g)"
      },
      "domainMin": 0,
      "domainMax": {
        "signal": "data('source')[0]['max fibre (g)']*1.1"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "protein (g)",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {
        "signal": "[0, radius]"
      },
      "zero": true,
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {
        "data": "source",
        "field": "protein (g)"
      },
      "domainMin": 0,
      "domainMax": {
        "signal": "data('source')[0]['max protein (g)']*1.2"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "salt (g)",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {
        "signal": "[0, radius]"
      },
      "zero": true,
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {
        "data": "source",
        "field": "salt (g)"
      },
      "domainMin": 0,
      "domainMax": {
        "signal": "data('source')[0]['max salt (g)']*1.2"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {
        "data": "table5",
        "field": "category"
      },
      "range": ["#ff2d1d", "grey"]
    },
    {
      "name": "color2",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {
        "data": "table5",
        "field": "Name"
      },
      "range": ["#ffb025"]
    }
  ],
  "encode": {
    "enter": {
      "x": {"signal": "radius"},
      "y": {"signal": "radius"}
    }
  },
  "layout": {
    "columns": 4,
    "padding": {
      "row": 50,
      "column": 30
    },
    "align": "all"
  },
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "name": "categories",
      "zindex": 1,
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "data": "table5",
          "name": "facet",
          "groupby": ["index", "Name"]
        }
      },
      "sort": {
        "field": "datum.index",
        "order": "ascending"
      },
      "title": {
        "text": {
          "signal": "parent.Name"
        },
        "color": "#d0d0d2",
        "frame": "group",
        "fontSize": 12,
        "fontWeight": "600",
        "baseline": "line-bottom",
        "dy": -5,
        "orient": "top",
        "lineHeight": 20
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "group",
          "name": "categories",
          "zindex": 1,
          "from": {
            "facet": {
              "data": "facet",
              "name": "facet2",
              "groupby": ["category"]
            }
          },
          "marks": [
            {
              "type": "line",
              "name": "category-line",
              "from": {
                "data": "facet2"
              },
              "encode": {
                "update": {
                  "interpolate": {
                    "value": "linear-closed"
                  },
                  "x": {
                    "signal": "scale(datum.key, datum.value) * cos(scale('angular', datum.key))"
                  },
                  "y": {
                    "signal": "scale(datum.key, datum.value) * sin(scale('angular', datum.key))"
                  },
                  "stroke": [
                    {
                      "test": "datum.category=='data'",
                      "scale": "color2",
                      "field": "Name"
                    },
                    {"value": "grey"}
                  ],
                  "strokeWidth": {
                    "signal": "datum.category=='data'?1:0"
                  },
                  "strokeDash": {
                    "value": [0]
                  },
                  "fill": [
                    {
                      "test": "datum.category=='data'",
                      "scale": "color2",
                      "field": "Name"
                    },
                    {"value": "grey"}
                  ],
                  "fillOpacity": {
                    "signal": "datum.category=='data'?1:0.3"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "text",
              "name": "value-text",
              "from": {
                "data": "facet2"
              },
              "encode": {
                "enter": {
                  "x": {
                    "signal": "(scale(datum.key, datum.value) +5) * cos(scale('angular', datum.key))"
                  },
                  "y": {
                    "signal": "(scale(datum.key, datum.value)+5) * sin(scale('angular', datum.key))"
                  },
                  "text": {
                    "signal": "datum.value==0?'':datum.category=='data'?datum.value:'' "
                  },
                  "align": [
                    {
                      "test": "abs(scale('angular', datum.key)) > PI / 2",
                      "value": "right"
                    },
                    {"value": "left"}
                  ],
                  "baseline": [
                    {
                      "test": "scale('angular', datum.key) > 0",
                      "value": "top"
                    },
                    {
                      "test": "scale('angular', datum.key) == 0",
                      "value": "middle"
                    },
                    {"value": "bottom"}
                  ],
                  "fill": {
                    "scale": "color2",
                    "field": "Name"
                  },
                  "opacity": {
                    "value": 0.6
                  },
                  "fontSize": {
                    "value": 9
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "rule",
          "name": "radial-grid",
          "from": {"data": "keys"},
          "zindex": 0,
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"value": 0},
              "y": {"value": 0},
              "x2": {
                "signal": "radius * cos(scale('angular', datum.key))"
              },
              "y2": {
                "signal": "radius * sin(scale('angular', datum.key))"
              },
              "stroke": {
                "value": "lightgray"
              },
              "strokeWidth": {
                "value": 0.5
              },
              "opacity": {"value": 0.2}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "key-label",
          "from": {"data": "keys"},
          "zindex": 1,
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {
                "signal": "(radius + 5) * cos(scale('angular', datum.key))"
              },
              "y": {
                "signal": "(radius + 5) * sin(scale('angular', datum.key))"
              },
              "text": {"field": "key"},
              "align": [
                {
                  "test": "abs(scale('angular', datum.key)) > PI / 2",
                  "value": "right"
                },
                {"value": "left"}
              ],
              "baseline": [
                {
                  "test": "scale('angular', datum.key) > 0",
                  "value": "top"
                },
                {
                  "test": "scale('angular', datum.key) == 0",
                  "value": "middle"
                },
                {"value": "bottom"}
              ],
              "fill": {
                "value": "white"
              },
              "opacity": {"value": 0.5},
             
              "fontSize":{"value":12}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "line",
          "name": "outer-line",
          "from": {
            "data": "radial-grid"
          },
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "interpolate": {
                "value": "linear-closed"
              },
              "x": {"field": "x2"},
              "y": {"field": "y2"},
              "stroke": {
                "value": "lightgray"
              },
              "strokeWidth": {
                "value": 1
              },
              "opacity": {"value": 0}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "rule",
          "name": "seperator",
          "from": {"data": "facet"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"signal": "140"},
              "y": {"signal": "-60"},
              "y2": {"signal": "60"},
              "stroke": {
                "signal": "'lightgray'"
              },
              "strokeOpacity": {
                "signal": "0.3"
              },
              "strokeWidth": [
                {
                  "test": "datum.index ==4||datum.index ==8||datum.index ==12",
                  "value": 0
                },
                {"value": 0.2}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```